# Why is insertion sort running O(n^2) on a sorted list?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm doing algorithm analysis in Python and in short I ran into what I suspect is a problem. I need to analyze the run time of insertion sort on sorted arrays so I have the following code

```
def insertionSort(arr1):
  t1 = time.time();
  insertion_sort.sort(arr1)
  t2 = time.time();
  print (len(arr1));
  print (str(t2-t1));
...
print ('Insertion Sort Beginning');

for x in range(0,15):
  #Creates arrays of various sizes with integers from 0-100 randomly sprawled about. They are named after the power of 10 the size is
  toSort1 = [randint(0,100)] * randint(100000,10000000);
  #Presorts the array, insertion sort is faster for small inputs
  sorted_list = insertion_sort.sort(toSort1);
  ##################################
  insertionSort(sorted_list);
```

The problem is the output of this is O(n^2)! I'm new to Python so I figure this is probably a semantics error I didn't catch. `insertion_sort` should be assumed to be correct, but can be reviewed [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/algorithms/0.1). This could only be the case if it was sorted in reverse order when it was timed but it was literally passed to the same sorter twice. How could this be?

This is a graphical representation of the output

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look not linear. It seems there is some issue at about 7000000. Before that point, it looks pretty linear and after that.. well.. not much can be said because there are few points. It could be that it's also linear but much steeper slope or that after that point it gets quadratic or something but this doesn't point exactly why... it might be that it's a problem stemming from memory allocation.

Comment: Insertion sort's advertised avg complexity is O(n^2). Not sure why you are surprised: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: @DeepSpace Sure, but it should be O(n) on an array that's already sorted.

Comment: The random list is pre-sorted before being passed to the routine which does a timed sort.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel I am running more test on 6 million - 10 million right now. I'll update shortly (or not lol)

Comment: @LegionDaeth you can start also by plotting the time in log scale and do a linear fit (not different than what you do now, but perhaps nicer to visually see) and also a linear fit to your data up to 7000000.

Comment: You'd get more accurate results using the `timeit` module to run several tests on the same data. Also, by default `timeit` disables garbage collection while it's doing its timings. And when doing timing tests like this (either with the `time` module or `timeit`) you should try to minimize other activity on your machine. For serious timings, I close my Web browser and may even disconnect from the Net.

Comment: But if you don't want to use `timeit`, if you're using Python 3.3+ you should use [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) rather than plain `time.time` for stuff like this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code for the insertion sort that you're using. SO questions are supposed to be self-contained, you can't expect people to go rummaging around on external sites looking for the code you're using.

Comment: Are you sure of the data structure that you are using? Python lists are not the same as C arrays. What about garbage collection - is it turned off? Python has aninterpreted overhead that might skew results, (but then modern processors have caching concerns that could affect timings, too).

Comment: @Paddy3118 This is essentially the same timed result for a sorted list.

Comment: I've reran this several times thus far with the same results. Linear correlation is .77 and there's no way I can explain that away.

Comment: I've tried everyone's suggestions, including disabling garbage collection but the result is always the same. Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. In my tests with list sizes from 1 million to 10 million, the timeit measurement corresponds to ±0.35µs per array unit. The code definitely will do n-1 comparisons for sorted lists of size n, so it is O(n). There must be a system aspect playing up in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I got linear time results with your program. [image]

I added implementation of insertion-sort and little modification of the code as below for this tests.

```
from random import randint
import time

def insertion_sort(arr):

    # Traverse through 1 to len(arr)
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):

        key = arr[i]

        # Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        # greater than key, to one position ahead
        # of their current position
        j = i-1
        while j >=0 and key < arr[j] :
                arr[j+1] = arr[j]
                j -= 1
        arr[j+1] = key

def insertionSort(arr1):
  t1 = time.time();
  insertion_sort(arr1)
  t2 = time.time();
  print str(len(arr1)) + ", " +  str(t2-t1)


print ('Insertion Sort Beginning');

for x in range(0,15):
  #Creates arrays of various sizes with integers from 0-100 randomly sprawled about. They are named after the power of 10 the size is
  toSort1 = [randint(0,100)] * randint(100000,10000000);
  #Presorts the array, insertion sort is faster for small inputs
  sorted_list = sorted(toSort1);
  ##################################
  insertionSort(sorted_list);
```

Hope it helps!